# problems with Linq skip take

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

i have this code..

```
        var documents = from d in db.Documents select d;
        documents = documents.OrderBy(d => d.Created);
        documents = documents.Skip(20).Take(10);
```

In db i have 25 documents (ids from 1 to 25). When i run this code i get documents from id 19 to 24.

If i write it like this

```
    documents = documents.Skip(20);
```

or like this

```
documents = documents.Skip(20).ToList().Take(10).AsQueryable();
```

I get documents from id 20 to 25..

What i am missing here??

Comment: When you talk about "documents 19 to 24" are you using 0-based indexing, or 1-based indexing? Can you show a [mcve]? (As an aside, your code is pretty hard to understand. I'd use something like `var actualPage = page ?? 1; var actualPageSize = pageSize ?? 10; var skip = (actualPage - 1) * actualPageSize; documents = documents.Skip(skip).Take(actualPageSize);`... and probably validate that you haven't been given negative inputs. I'd also use a return value rather than accepting `documents` by ref...

Comment: At this point, it looks like it's a broken provider - or the data isn't what you believe it to be. Have you had a look at the generated SQL? (Note that you're not ordering by Id, which *could* potentially explain it...)

Comment: what is the value of skip?   in the "if i write like this" part

Comment: forget the last line, you sould never make a .ToList() and then start querying again on same information.,  the first line , document skip(20) does exaclty what you tell i to , it skipps the first 20 and give you the rest wich in your case is 20-25

Comment: Yes, so then why when i use this documents.Skip(20).Take(10) i get different documents?

Comment: is the query the same?

Comment: it can be something with ordering maybe??

Comment: @Thorarins Yes it is

Comment: you could put the order in the query

Comment: Go check your data in the created field.  25 seems to have data you don't expect.  It was probably entered as the wrong month or year.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not what you think.  The problem is the `created` date in `id=25` is not in order.

Comment: created date in last 6 documents are same... maybe this is an issue?

Comment: That would do it as well.

Comment: If you are ordering by repeated data you probably want two fields in your order by.  add a `.ThenBy(...)` for your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering your sequence by `created` first, so why would you expect the output to be ordered (or the selection based on) by `id`?

Doing the `Skip` first and the `OrderBy` second changed the output, because it was probably ordered by `Id` initially, then you took the last few in the sequence, then ordered them by date again.